# Access Desktop as root user in linux

Tags: linux, mount, iso-image, root

I know the command to get to your Desktop is cd ~/Desktop. This however does not work as the root user. However I need to be the root user because I would like to move a file, from my desktop into my /mnt/disk folder so that I can mount my .iso. I can't click-and-drag either as I do not have permission. I've been trying for about an hour and am quite frustrated; so any and all help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what distro/desktop environment? and why can't you use a terminal to do it?

Comment: I _can_ use the terminal, I just don't know how. I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 --- GNOME too I believe.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: The command, cd ~/Desktop doesn't work. It says the directory cannot be found (because it is basing it off of /root, not /home)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access a folder under another users home directory instead of using `~` you need to use `~username`.  So I would do something like `~zoredache/Desktop`.  You could also simply use the full path.  Typically on a Linux system the home directories are under `/home`, so you could use `cd /home/zoredache/Desktop`.

If you cannot access your home directory while logged in as root, then that indicates that you may be try to access a filesystem that was mounted with [fuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/).  As a security measure, by default, fuse will setup restrictions to prevent any else from accessing the filesystem except the user that mounted it.

Comment: Whenever I tried going through my user it said that the file/directory does not exist =/

Comment: But using your line it worked, thank you... now let's see if I can figure the rest out :]

Comment: what he wants,seems to be to mount the ISO - which dosen't actually involve moving the disk at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open Nautilus window with root permissions you can run (Alt+F2) command:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

You will be asked for your password, but in that window, the Home and Desktop will be from root's perspective, so you will have to browse to your desktops in that window.

Close it when you done, and be carefull. You can remove /bin/ or /boot/ for example.